# How to install pyobjc and Foundation into a virtualenv on mac?

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, virtualenv, pyobjc

After creating a new virtualenv and `pip install pyobjc`, I still cannot use pyobjc on that virtualenv.

Although I can import Foundation on the system python, I need to install alpha unstable dependencies that would dirty my system and thus need to use a virtualenv for this project.

```
ImportError: No module named Foundation
```

Example

```
python -c "from Foundation import NSAutoreleasePool"
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ImportError: No module named Foundation

After searching and trying to solve it, I feel there is something macs do by default for the system python that sets this up. In order to install it to a virtualenv, maybe it's not possible. Would installing it to a conda environment be possible? Docker?

The main problem is I really really don't want to install some of the other pyobjc related dependencies into a non-virtual env as they are fairly unstable. One obvious answer is another computer for this project, but at the same time, I feel there must be a more pragmatic solution out there. A key insight would be finding out how pyobjc testers run their CI tests across different environments.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually install PyObjC in the virtualenv? I develop and regularly use PyObjC using virtual environments (virtualenv and venv).